# USB Drive (Dual, Type C and USB) doesn't show any of my files when plugged in to my Ubuntu laptop, yet shows all files on my Android

Tags: ubuntu, usb, android, file-transfer

I've got a 128GB dual USB drive (type C and USB) which has around 34 GBs of data on it initially (was using it for backup). I transferred some files from my android to the drive, all video files in seperate folders, amounting to around 3-4 GBs. When I plugged the drive into my PC (HP Probook 640 G2 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), not a single folder or file is visible, and in their place are two empty folders, 'DCIM' and 'LOST.DIR'. The driver's properties show that all the data is on the drive itself, just not visible to me.

Can anyone please help me with this? I looked for similar problems but all existing questions are different than my issue.

I *could* use a recovery software to get all my files but I'll lose all my folders which I've so meticulously organised and named, *and* all my files will be renamed to some random code rather than their original names, which will result in *so* much more work for me, so I really don't want to resort to that option.

---

To check whether the drive had corrupted or something I plugged it into my android again and all the files are visible there, so the problem only occurs on my PC. The files aren't marked as hidden or anything, they're just not visible, instead have been replaced with aforementioned folders.

Accessing the drive folder via terminal and using *ls* command shows all my folders as they were, but every line is like this.

```
ls: cannot access 'Documents': No such file or directory
```

When I try to *cd* into a folder it says the same, that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Please provide the output of `df /the/drive/path` and `grep /the/drive/path /proc/mounts`.

Comment: In Ubuntu, what is the output of `sudo file -skr /dev/sdX`? (replace `X` with the right letter).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski /dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector. - DOS/MBR boot sector, exFAT filesystem (1<<8) sectors per cluster.  It goes on to show number of clusters and a serial number, ending with - data

Comment: @DanielB output of df drivepath is just the storage of the drive, percentage used and mount path, could you clarify upon the second command as to how I should execute that?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add exact information there.

Comment: Have you tried to run `fschk` in check mode only without repair to see if the filesystem shows problems?